# How to use flutter flavors for firebase firestore using flutter_flavor package?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have used [flutter_falvor](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavor) package to create flutter flavors (dev & prod). The app runs in two different modes now (dev or prod), however, I need the app to connect to a different Firebase Firestore instance when it runs on the dev mode. How can I achieve this using this package (if possible)? if not, what are the options that might work for my case?

So fat, I've created to main files, main_dev.dart and main_prod.dart, and this is the code I am using in the main function.

```
 // set up the environment
  FlavorConfig(
    name: "DEVELOP",
    color: Colors.red,
    location: BannerLocation.bottomStart,
    variables: {
      "env": Environment.development, // enum -> dev or prod depending on the file that runs
    },
  );
  
   runApp(MyApp());
```